# Can cUrl redirect to URL (post) page?

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

After executing cUrl method, my browser stays on same page, but loads content of page called in a curl init.

Is it possible to redirect browser to that URL?

```
$ch=curl_init($URL); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$DataToSend);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$varResponse=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

echo $varResponse;

exit;
```

**UPDATE: So, is not about redirecting, it's about posting data using curl.**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: to redirect you don't need curl. just return a 301 redirect https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=http%20redirect%20code

Comment: it's not about redirecting, it's about posting data using curl... so that's why i need curl

Comment: You could redirect there with a `header('Location...')` but whether the target site will show what you intend is unknown. It could depend on a session cookie for example, which may result in a different display for your user's client browser than for what your server POSTed to it.

Comment: @user198003 You asked "Is it possible to redirect browser to that URL".  what about posting data you need to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl is for calling a URL and fetching the response.

If you echo it to the browser then the browser will show the response that was fetched from the URL.

**Example**

If you have a website. with domain website.com.

And when a user goes to the website.com home page, you do

```
$ch=curl_init("www.google.com"); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$DataToSend);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$varResponse=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

echo $varResponse;

exit;
```

The user will still be on **website.com** but the content of the page will show the html that google.com returns.

Comment: So, url will always be website.com? No way it can be "changed" to www.google.com?

Comment: correct. in this example instead of printing you own html to the browser you print the result of another web page

Answer (score 0):

This is how to redirect the browser to the URL gathered by cURL:

```
$ch=curl_init($URL); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$DataToSend);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$varResponse=curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

header('Location: ' . $varResponse);
exit;
```

Comment: tnx, but is not about redirecting, it's about posting data using curl